# javascript for pinging in Controller or View in web2py?

Tags: jquery, python, linux, web2py

If I have a program like below, that need to be used in web2py, should I put this in controller or view ? Below is a jquery code that was from this link http://jsfiddle.net/GSSCD/203/

The below code is jquery code for checking if there is any server alive or not

```
function ping(ip, callback) {

    if (!this.inUse) {
        this.status = 'unchecked';
        this.inUse = true;
        this.callback = callback;
        this.ip = ip;
        var _that = this;
        this.img = new Image();
        this.img.onload = function () {
            _that.inUse = false;
            _that.callback('responded');

        };
        this.img.onerror = function (e) {
            if (_that.inUse) {
                _that.inUse = false;
                _that.callback('responded', e);
            }

        };
        this.start = new Date().getTime();
        this.img.src = "http://" + ip;
        this.timer = setTimeout(function () {
            if (_that.inUse) {
                _that.inUse = false;
                _that.callback('timeout');
            }
        }, 1500);
    }
}
var PingModel = function (servers) {
    var self = this;
    var myServers = [];
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(servers, function (location) {
        myServers.push({
            name: location,
            status: ko.observable('unchecked')
        });
    });
    self.servers = ko.observableArray(myServers);
    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.servers(), function (s) {
        s.status('checking');
        new ping(s.name, function (status, e) {
            s.status(status);
        });
    });
};
```

Comment: Ultimately it has to end up in the rendered html.  I would put this in the view.  I don't think you want to embed more than one or two lines of javascript in a controller unless you have extremely good reason to.

Comment: Thanks ! I think I will put it in view as you suggested